# CSS div in centre of page and width of content inside

Tags: css

I have this CSS for a div:

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

which puts it in the centre of the page, i had the width set to a fixed width of `800px` but i want to change it so its the width of the content inside (not the width of the page)

i tried setting the width to `100%` and i also tried setting `min-width:800px;` but both of these just set the div to the full page width

how can i make this div stay in the centre of the page and only be the width of the content inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following on the container :

```css
    .modal-dialog {   
        width: -moz-fit-content;
        width: -webkit-fit-content;
        width: fit-content;
        margin: auto;
        outline: 2px dashed red;
    }
    .content {
      width: 50vw; 
      height: 50vh;
      background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no container

Comment: That's a term referring to `.modal-dialog`

Comment: ah i see - there isnt a div inside the modal-dialog though

Comment: @charlie Update: the inside div is blue the modal has a red dashed border.

Comment: yep - got it. seems to be working, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

This will put your div in the center and make the div as wide as its content.

Comment: still full page width